# Why isn't TypeScript inferring rest params correctly in function implementation?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have defined a function that takes a string name and variable number of remaining params that it should infer from the provided interface. When calling this function, the inference is done correctly, but it is not inferred within the function implementation.

```js
interface ThingParams {
  A: [isThing: boolean];
  B: [thingCount: number];
}

function DoThing<T extends keyof ThingParams>( name: T, ...params: ThingParams[T] )
{
  if ( name === 'A' )
  {
    // Why is foo typed as boolean | number instead of being correctly inferred to be boolean???
    const foo = params[0]
  }
}

DoThing( 'A', true ); // Correctly limits what I can pass
DoThing( 'B', 5 ); // All good

DoThing( 'B', false ); // Errors, as expected
```

It seems like it should be able to narrow the type of `foo` based on the condition assigning a specific `T`. I'm hoping to do this without balooning the types with something like

```
interface ThingA { name: 'A', value: [isThing: boolean] }
interface ThingB { name: 'B', ... }
type ThingParams = ThingA | ThingB;
...
```

when all I need is a simple mapping. Is there something I can do better in the definition of `DoThing` to get it to correctly narrow the types within the implementation?

Comment: This is a combination of two missing features in TS; checking generic values does not re-constrain their type parameters (this is requested at [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) among other places), and destructured rest parameters do not participate in discriminated unions (this is requested at [ms/TS#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680)). The closest I can get to what you want is [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1ApXw) admittedly clunky code. Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Narrowing the type of `...params` based on the value of `name` is currently not possible because the type of `name` is a generic type. See [#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for a similar issue.

Control flow analysis is often not behaving well when generic types are involved. Ideally, we should remove generics from the function. We can describe the relationship between `name` and `...params` using a tuple union.

```
type ThingParamsUnion = { 
  [K in keyof ThingParams]: [name: K, ...params: ThingParams[K]] 
}[keyof ThingParams]

// type ThingParamsUnion = [name: "A", isThing: boolean] | [name: "B", thingCount: number]
```

`ThingParamsUnion` takes `ThingParams` and constructs a *discriminating* union of tuples which describe the possible combination of parameter types. We can use `ThingParamsUnion` to type the parameters of `DoThing` using a *spread parameter*.

Now to get TypeScript to properly discrimate the union, we need some *ugly* destructuring

```
function DoThing(...args: ThingParamsUnion) {
  const [name] = args

  if (name === 'A')
  {
    const [_, ...params] = args

    const foo = params[0]
    //    ^? foo: boolean
  }
}
```

I initially hoped that we could destructure `name` and `params` like this:

```
function DoThing(...[name, ...params]: ThingParamsUnion) {
  if (name === 'A')
  {
    const foo = params[0]
    //    ^? foo: number | boolean
  }
}
```

But it seems like the compiler does not properly discriminate in this scenario.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMAKcpwC2AzsgN4BQyyAggFzIDawxG2DARgPZcA2EcEAF0A3FWQAhBozCYQWAMJcAruAYhlhDtFEUAvhQpgAngAcUbeXgIkAqiGBcQyALzlk4xgGlkoZAGsIYy4YNDlcfCJiIWkQIggGLwAaZAA6dNNIkgZLCJtibyEhDz1GQODQ3OsooUMYVQQwR2cAES5cgAp01PwsYhzw6rsHJwBKCkpqBCdiMCY4wghit17iQ2pgUI6FlBc95AByGgPx6knqZGmQWaYAfRTuzPzl5FX1i6ubmB5XZCeoxgABlqF2QAHowaCAHoAfmQ3y4nB4-EE4gMBgobU6h2OKTAUGUKFGInBkKUUCgEEavGMyF4wEIwDApAA7ug4HMAJKXQR-ODENZY8IdQ4SA4pACsyGJpNovF4yCwPAAJoYhdgRQcxSl4LxiESSRDkABRClcKDEFL85AQAAe5kaEGVQA)